# Codename One javafx.util.pair

Tags: java, android, javafx, netbeans, codenameone

Hello dear Codename One Community,

I've written a class in which is use the package javafx.util.Pair.
When I want to build the application I get no Errors.
But sending an Android build to the server fails. In the Error Log file i found following line:

> "Warning: com.mycompany.myapp.Main: can't find referenced class
>   javafx.util.Pair"

Does this straight up mean that the javafx.util.Pair class is not available for the use in Codename One ?

Thanks in advance & kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One doesn't support the full Java API and doesn't support JavaFX. I'm guessing you changed the classpath of the project, that won't work and would trigger errors when you try to actually build the project.

You need to adapt your project to work with the Codename One API's and JDK subset. The logic for this is explained in [this article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Fortunately i was able to find a work around.